# No polkit authentication agent found in AwesomeWM

Tags: awesome, polkit

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my computer, and recently I've abandoned Gnome in favor of AwesomeWM. [I've since learned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/623836/415533) that a DE is much more fleshed-out than just using a WM, so I've had to rice and patch the WM along the way, such as various widgets, etc.

My latest discovery is using Balena Etcher to flash an ISO onto a USB stick. I get an error that `No polkit authentication agent found`. Assuming that the policykit authentication agent simply wasn't autostarting in AwesomeWM (for whatever reason), I found my policykit via `sudo apt list | grep policykit`, put that in my `rc.lua` as `awful.spawn.with_shell("policykit-1-gnome")`, and restarted Awesome.

That didn't do anything, I'm still receiving the error. So what is causing that authentication failure?

Comment: Firstly you should confirm your polkit.service is running or not.